# is not equal sign != and <> is not working in my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using two table like, user_details where the user_id and name are its field. Second table is group_user where user_id and group_id are its field. Here group_id is related to group table which I am creating a group.
I want those names who are not in group. I am using mysql query like,

```
SELECT 
    user_details.name 
FROM 
    group_users 
    INNER JOIN
        user_details 
        ON 
        group_users.user_id = user_details.user_id 
WHERE 
    group_id != 160
;
```

or

```
SELECT 
    user_details.name 
FROM 
    group_users   
    INNER JOIN
        user_details
        ON 
        group_users.user_id = user_details.user_id 
WHERE 
    group_id <> 160
;
```

But I am not getting particular result for that mean `!= and <>` is not working proper.

Comment: Are you trying to get users not in group 160, or users in groups other than 160? Because the latter is what that query is actually asking.

Comment: is your column `group_id` set as INT in your database?

Comment: @Uueerdo : Yeah I am trying to get users not in group 160.

Comment: your query looks fine. I would recommend re-creating your issue using this site: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: your query looks fine. I recreated it here using SQL Fiddle: Check it out : **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61e8c/2/0**

Comment: We'll need to see a schema and some input data to be able to help here. As @CodeGodie says, a Fiddle will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT ud.name 
FROM user_details AS ud
LEFT JOIN group_users AS gu ON ud.user_id = gu.user_id AND gu.group_id = 160
WHERE gu.user_id IS NULL
;
```

or this

```
SELECT ud.name 
FROM user_details AS ud
WHERE ud.user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT user_id 
   FROM group_users AS gu 
   WHERE gu.group_id = 160
)
;
```

In the first, you'd be finding all users that didn't have an association with the group. In the second, you'd be finding users not in the set of users associated with that group. (Same result, but depending on data distribution one may be faster than the other.)

Comment: be careful with NOT IN (), also check your alias `WHERE gu.user_id NOT IN (`  in second block line 3, as it may be out of scope

Comment: @DrewPierce Good catch on the alias. What is the concern with `NOT IN`?

Comment: not in () and nullability issues, will plop a few links your way. Just something to look out for, that's all

Comment: You perfect...Its worked...@Uueerdo

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing SQL. Try being more specific about which column *group_id* is referring to.

Change the WHERE clause to `your_table_name.group_id != 160`

Comment: If it were ambiguous MySQL wouldn't even let it run.

Comment: Correct, but who knows if he's handling errors within PHP. Including some info about the SQL output will be helpful. Also, @Viral, If you're using PHP PDO you can call `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` to verify whether or not your SQL query is even running.

Comment: @Evan : Thanks and I am sure about group_id and also where clause is not working what you have specified.